# Excel for Mac conditional matching statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos

In Excel for Mac.

What I am trying to do is create a formula in cell A13 that will take a value from cell A1 and look for a match from a a list of multiple values from a list (column a) from tab b. If the value of A1 matches a value in column a from tab 2, then I want A13 to hold the value from the cell adjacent to the cell that A13 is a match for (from column A on tab 2).

Comment: Google `VLOOKUP`.  I won't attempt a formal answer because you have given so little information in your question.

Comment: You should have shown us what you've already attempted.

Comment: According to the description of the [tag:excel] tag, *"General help regarding MS Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User."*  IN other words, you should have posted this on the Super User SE site.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))
```